# Sum separable partial differential equation over general domain

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

First off, thank you for taking your time out and considering my question. I just have a (rather) general question on partial differential equations.

So consider the following. Let $(x,y) \mapsto u(x,y)$ be some sufficiently smooth real-valued function over a rather general domain $\mathcal{F} \subset R^2$. And using subscripts to denote partial differentiation, suppose that, 
$$
u_x(x,y) = g_1(x) \\
u_y(x,y) = g_2(y)  
$$
In particular, note that $g_1$ is only a function of $x$ and $g_2$ is only a function of $y$. Now, if the domain $\mathcal{F}$ were rectangular in the form $[a,b] \times [c,d]$, then using the usual fundamental theorem of calculus, we would obtain $u(x,y) = \int_a^x g_1(\eta)d\eta + \int_c^y g_2(\eta) d\eta$.

But what about the case when $\mathcal{F}$ is rather general? That is, it could be connected, simply-connected, etc.? I can still see how $u(x,y)$ would have a similar separably additive form as above, but what about the region of integration? That is, do we have to consider, for each point $(x,y) \in \mathcal{F}$, the $x$-section $\mathcal{F}_y$ and $y$-section $\mathcal{F}_x$ of the domain $\mathcal{F}$ and integrate? Would it have the form like, 
$$
u(x,y)
= \int_{\mathcal{F}_y} g_1(\eta) d\eta + \int_{\mathcal{F}_x} g_2(\eta) d\eta
$$
(and plus some constant of integration if it needs be)? And if it is indeed this form, to recover back the partial derivatives, we can't use the typical fundamental theorem of calculus, but we need to consider the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, correct?

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

PS. I'm aware that such sum-separable differential form can, via some change of variables, be rewritten into the wave equation. However, the traditional wave equation in $(t,x)$ where $x \in R^1$ allows for a very general consideration in the spatial coordinate $x$ but usually takes the time coordinate $t$ to be only the positive real line. But in my case above, this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $y$ still runs from $c$ to $d$, and for a fixed $y$, $x\in [a(y),b(y)]$, and for $y=c$ we have $x=a$. Integrate the first equation first
$$
u(x,y) = \int_{a(y)}^x g_1(\eta)d\eta + H(y) = G_1(x) - G_1(a(y)) + H(y), 
$$
where $G_1' = g_1$. Now we take partial derivative with respect to $y$:
$$
g_2(y) = u_y(x,y) = -\partial_y\big(G_1(a(y))\big) + H_y = -g_1(a(y)) a_y(y) + H_y(y).
$$ 
Now we can integrate $y$ from $c$ for $H$:
$$
H(y) = \int_c^y g_2(\eta)d\eta + \int_c^y g_1(a(\eta)) a_{\eta}(\eta) d\eta = G_2(y) - G_2(c) + G_1(a(y)) - G_1(a),
$$
Plugging back to the first equation we have:
$$
u(x,y) = G_1(x) - G_1(a)+ G_2(y) -G_2(c)= \int_a^x g_1 + \int^y_c g_2.
$$
For general simply-connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can approximate it by a sequence of collection of horizontal rectangles, and perform the integration one by one, then prove the convergence upon certain smoothness assumptions.

Comment: Thanks Shuhao Cao. That's pretty much what I thought above when I used the x-section and y-section of a set (i.e. freezing one coordinate and integrating over the other coordinate). But I was wondering if there's a more general formula that directly uses the general set forms rather than through approximating via rectangles. Thanks again!